# How to run a program, one after another

Tags: linux, terminal, long-running-processes

I'm running many programs (all written in fortran). Right now I'm running one program `(./first)` but I would like that once it is finished another one starts running `(./second)`, and once that other program finishes the next one starts `(./third)` and so on. Any idea how can I do that from the terminal? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

how about

```
./first && ./second && ./third
```

or

```
./first ; ./second ; ./third
```

in the first case, the chain is interrupted, if one of the programs fails (exits with exit code != 0). in the second case, the applications keep on running, even if one of them (e.g. ./second) is going to fail.

Comment: Note the corollary: if you are writing the programs, then you are responsible for making sure that your program correctly returns 0 when it is successful, and non-zero when it fails.

Comment: But what if the first program is already running?

Comment: then I guess there's no nice way to do that, other than having a while-true-loop grepping for the PID of the running process and waiting to start the next one. generally, I'd recommend using shell scripts taking care of things like that.

Comment: It can be done, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `bash` or a compatible shell:

1. Put `first` in the background by pressing Ctrl-Z (not necessary if it's already backgrounded)
2. Run `wait && ./second && ./third`